# No puedo grabar archivos .txt con QFileDialog C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt

Este es mi código:

```
void MainWindow::save(){
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save Text File"), path, tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));
    if (fileName != "")
    {
       QFileInfo info(fileName);
       path = info.absoluteDir().absolutePath();
       QFile file(path);
       if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
           QString text = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
           QTextStream out(&file);
           out << text ;
           file.close();
       }
    }
}
```

Luego de llamar el método a través de un `pushButton` no se crea ningún archivo `txt`.

```
connect(ui->saveButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(save()));
```

Este es el mensaje que aparece en el Log:

> QIODevice::write (QFile, "C:\Users\kfg\Desktop"): device not open

Comment: Hi! KGGC, this site is purely Spanish site, consider translating your question or migrate to the site in English http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Gracias, acabo de modificar el post.

Comment: hace mucho que no uso Qt pero es ! es correcto donde esta en el if(! sin un return; debajo. Saludos

Comment: igual con este link http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfile.html#reading-files-directly me entiende mejor, hay un caso para WriteOnly. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Gracias! funcionó quitando "!", también tuve que cambiar esto:
path = info.absoluteDir().absolutePath();
por esto:
QFile file(QFileInfo(fileName).absoluteFilePath());

Comment: Puede publicar la solucion como respuesta, si lo desea y aceptar su respuesta pasado unos dias, quedando esta pregunta como respondida (solucionada) de esa manera sera mas facil si otros usuarios tiene el mismo problema o similar el solucionarlo. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Mi Solución:

```
void MainWindow::save()
{
    QString path = QDir::currentPath();
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save Text File"), path, tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));

    if(filename.isEmpty())
        return;

    QFile file(filename);

    if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly |
                  QFile::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << " Could not open file for writing";
        return;
    }

    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
    file.flush();
    file.close();
}
```